# Firebase authentication rules for multiple databases

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have two databases in the same project. I initialize them using the syntax:

```
// Initialize Firebase
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/messaging";
import "firebase/functions";
import "firebase/storage";

var config = {
 ....
};
var forecastConfig = {
  ....
};
var firebaseDefault = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var firebaseForecast = firebase.initializeApp(forecastConfig, "forecast");

export {
  firebaseDefault as firebase,
  firebaseForecast
};
```

However, when I try to use the following authentication rules on the database corresponding to "forecast":

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

the database is unable to read in any data. I have to use the following unsafe rules in order to allow it to read in the data:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

It appears that authentication in the main database does not transfer to the other database in the same project - how do I enable this?

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html

Comment: @DougStevenson what would the analogous code in Javascript be? Could you give a complete answer please?